# facebook access_token request return NOTHING

Tags: php, facebook, authentication, fbconnect, access-token

it's been 5 days that I'm stuck in the implementation of a simple fb login and I'm banging my head like a motherf***r. anyways.

I'm at the point that I'm trying to set the accessToken by hand.
like shown in this post.

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/418#issuecomment-2605012

the only problem is that the oauth/access_token call returns *nothing*
and I'm guessing that it's a pretty messed up behaviour.
this is the snippet I use to make the call

```
                $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=".FB_APPID."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($curUrl)."&client_secret=".FB_APPSECRET."&code=".$_GET['code'];
                log_to_file("curPageURL: ".$token_url);
                $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
                log_to_file("resp: ".$respone);
```

the log_to_file is a custm method that logs the taken message in a file so that I can have the log situation in a *tail -f* scenario.

what happens here is that the log "resp: ". returns nothing at all.

did anyone face the same problem?

thx in advance. this thing is driving me insane.

and  I can officially state that the fb sdk is the most buggy and worse-documented service
I've ever used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook has the most badly-documented API in the world. I remember the time I used it and couldn't help swearing all the time ! :) Here is a piece of pseudo-code that did work for me. It gains permission from a user to post a link on his wall. I'm just posting it so that maybe you can take some hints and make your code work:

```
<?php

//A function for cURL operations.
function callFb($url)
{
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => $url,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
            ));

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $result;
}

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=".urlencode("<the_url_where_the_user_is_redirected_after_granting_permission>")."&client_secret=<your_client_secret>";

/* Get access token. */
$access_token = callFb($url);

/* Parse the result to get access token */
$access_token = substr($access_token, strpos($access_token, "=")+1, strlen($access_token));

/* Save access token, if you want to for future.*/
mysql_query("INSERT INTO fb_auth_tokens (id,auth_token) VALUES('$_GET[id]','$auth_token')");

/* Post to users wall */

$apprequest_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed";
$mymessage="Hello World !";
$parameters = "?access_token=" . $access_token . "&message=" .
urlencode($mymessage) .
        "&link=".urlencode("<link_that_you_want_to_post>").
        "&description=<description_of_the_link>".
        "&method=post";
$myurl = $apprequest_url . $parameters;
$result = callFb($myurl);

// Thy shall be done. :)
```

Comment: funny, I ended up with a solution that uses curl without reading ur reply. thx anyway, to me it also works like a charm. the secret is setting your auth token by hand, I cannot f_ing believe it. fb sdk is a piece of junk.